# SSL Certificate Error when running jupyterlab nbconvert to webpdf

Tags: python, ssl, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I have a notebook which I want to convert to webpdf. I am able to convert to a pdf using the below line from the command line:

jupyter nbconvert --to pdf 'NB.ipynb' --template='base.tex.j2'

This however messes up some of the formatting of graphs in the notebook, hence I want to convert to webpdf instead. However when I run the below:

jupyter nbconvert --to webpdf --allow-chromium-download 'NB.ipynb' --template='base.tex.j2'

I get the following ssl certificate error:

urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='storage.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /chromium-browser-snapshots/Win_x64/588429/chrome-win32.zip (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Any idea how to allow my computer to bypass the SSL certificate for this? I know for pip install for example, one can add "--trusted-host pypi.python.org" for example, but this doesn't work for jupyter nbconvert. Thanks in advance for any help!